# Hibernate Caching - Empty table

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I left our application running overnight with JProfiler to analyse the performance bottlenecks and something I uncovered was that a query that was executed very frequently was taking up a significant amount of time - nothing new. The difference this time compared to normal was that there was no data in the table. The query did execute quickly (2.8ms) but I was wondering if there was anything I could do to 'cache' the output that there is no results?

Answer (score 1):

That's what the [query cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-cache) (which must be coupled with the second-level cache) is for. A query that searches in an empty table, however should be extremely fast, and I doubt this is the cause of any bottleneck.

Comment: Am I right in thinking the query cache maps the query to a collection of primary keys? If so since no results are ever returned, would the second-level cache be required? I agree querying the table isn't a performance bottleneck but it is taking much longer than I'd like (and impacting performance to a certain extent) - 2.8ms is quick but doing it hundreds of thousands of times adds up

Comment: Well, if you know that your table will always be empty, then you shouldn't even execute the query. If it can become non-empty, then eventually the query will return results, and then you'd better have a second-level cache, or ou will have a big N + 1 problem.